# Obtener valor de una etiqueta span dentro de un DIV

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hola necesito obtener el valor de la etiqueta data-cal-date dentro del span al hacer click en la clase cal-month-day.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que tengo de codigo es esto que me trae el valor pero el del primer div que es = "2021-12-28"

```
$('.cal-month-day').click(function(){ 
    dia = $('.cal-month-day span').attr('data-cal-date');
   alert(dia);
});
```

lo que no puedo hacer es que por ej la hacer click en el dia 5 me traiga "2022-01-05"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si quieres ayuda más rápida te recomiendo que peges el código en forma de texto, sino nos obligas a reproducirlo a mano, y depende de lo perezosos que estemos te ayudaremos o no. Mírate [ask] y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Lectura recomendada https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/65107

Comment: Creo que te confundes... no somos tus empleados. No vienes aquí a decirnos qué quieres/necesitas, si no a decirnos qué hiciste y no funcionó para ver si podemos ayudarte a que funcione. Es un detalle muy importante, ese de añadir el código de lo que has intentado hacer y qué problema tienes.

Comment: Perdón a todos, ahora si esta mas completa la pregunta.

Comment: Gracias, ahora está mejor, pero estaria aún mejor si no usaras imágenes para ningún tipo de código, incluido el HTML del principio (si, lo se, somos tikis-mikis, pero es por el bien de todos, incluido el tuyo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando jquery deberias probar esto.

Sustituye esto:

```
dia = $('.cal-month-day span').attr('data-cal-date');
```

por esto

```
dia = $(this).find('span').attr('data-cal-date');
```

En este snippet lo puedes ver funcionando:

```js
$('.cal-month-day').click(function(){ 
   dia = $(this).find('span').attr('data-cal-date');
   console.log(dia);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="call-cell1 call-cell">
  <div class="cal-month-day">
    <span data-cal-date="2022-01-07">7</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="call-cell1 call-cell">
  <div class="cal-month-day">
    <span data-cal-date="2022-01-08">8</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="call-cell1 call-cell">
  <div class="cal-month-day">
    <span data-cal-date="2022-01-09">9</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="call-cell1 call-cell">
  <div class="cal-month-day">
    <span data-cal-date="2022-01-10">10</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="call-cell1 call-cell">
  <div class="cal-month-day">
    <span data-cal-date="2022-01-11">11</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ya nos diras si lo has podido implementar en tu código.

Comment: gracias me funciono perfecto!

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza la función `querySelectorAll` para recorrer todos los nodos que buscas, luego con dataset obtienes los datos del `atributo data-*`.

```javascript
document.querySelectorAll(".cal-month-day")
    .forEach(btn => {
         btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
         var dia = event.target.dataset.calDate;
         console.log(dia)
     });
});
```

Ver código funcionando en https://jsfiddle.net/k0qrcj6u/

Importante saber que cuando usas data-* los guiones se comportan como camelcase, por eso no queda `dataset.cal-date`, si no que queda como `dataset.calDate`.

Ojo esto es vanilla javascript(js puro), no Jquery.

Comment: Seguramente contestaste antes de saber que hay varios `cal-month-day`. Tu solución no funciona con varios porque `querySelector` solo coge el primero que ve.

Comment: gracias, ahí lo corregí.